# Getting count of boolean MYSQL

Tags: mysql, database, count

I am having trouble to get information from my MySQL table. I have a table similar to the one below and I want to see how many `boolean=1` entries I have for each day. I tried to use `count(boolean)` where date is something like '12/__/2015' but I get the sum although I want individual result sets for each day.

```
>     id/time   date        boolean(TINYINT(1))
>     1 12.11   12/23/2015  0
>     2 12.12   12/23/2015  1
>     3 12.13   12/23/2015  1
>     4 12.14   12/23/2015  1
>     5 12.15   12/23/2015  0
>     6 13.11   12/25/2015  1
>     7 13.12   12/25/2015  0
>     8 13.13   12/25/2015  0
>     9 13.14   12/25/2015  0
>     10 13.15  12/25/2015  1
```

Comment: select date-field  , count(boolean-field) as boolean_count from table where boolean = 1 group by  date

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT count(boolean), date from [yourtable] where boolean=1 group by date
```

That should give you the counts you need, while ignoring the time column.

Comment: you are missing the condition where "boolean = 1"

Comment: You, sir, are correct.  Fixed.

Comment: hey @Monveu the above should do it...